# GIF format as png?

Tags: image, url, format, png, gif

I'm seeing some images online that end in .png but appear as GIF. How is this possible?
Example:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/loading/6267221601681408/5689792285114368.png

Comment: What makes you think it's a GIF?  There is such a thing as an animated PNG.

Answer (score 1):

This is a GIF file, with an `.png` extension. Though the extension is "wrong", many image viewers (including browsers) can still it interpret them correctly because they don't believe blindly what the extension says (remember that the "extension" is just a hint), but they look into the image content. The first bytes of most common image formats allow to easily identify the image type. In this case, you can check (looking at the image content, say, in some hexadecimal editor/viewer) that the file content starts with the ASCII characters "GIF89a".